# add number to all elements of a list within a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I have a class with a list, and I would like to add a number to all the elements of that list, but not to every list in the class. I tried this:

```
class class_name:
    def __init__(self,list_name,other_list):
        self.list_name = list_name
        self.other_list = other_list

list1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
list2 = [4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]    

data = [0]*len(list1)    

for i,(l1,l2) in enumerate(zip(list1,list2)):
    data[i] = class_name(l1,l2)

[(x + 5.0).list_name  for x in data]
```

and it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'float'
```

edit: people seem to not understand what I want. In the real code I have, the lists have been added to a class (in this case data) which I've been working with, but one of the lists in the class (specifically referring to magnitudes) needs to be calibrated. I do this by adding a number to every element in that list to calibrate it. This has to be done to the list connected to the class it's in, so I can't edit the list before putting it into the class.

I already have this class created much earlier in my code, and I needed it to be the way it was before so that I could work with all the elements. Now, later in the code, I want to calibrate this magnitude list within the class. Is there a way to do that?

maybe this attempt better illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
[x.list_name for x in data] = [x.list_name+5  for x in data]
```

this also doesn't work, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to list comprehension
```

I just feel like it makes people understand what I need.

Comment: How do you imagine `x + 5.0` is going to work? x is an instance, it is pretty unclear what you actually want

Comment: Can you please clean up your code and use better variable names? For instance, I've almost given you bad advice twice because I keep forgetting that `class_name` is your class and `class_names` is some kind of list I don't understand the purpose of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Map function for python.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools

```
class class_name:
    def __init__(self,list_name,other_list):
        self.list_name = list_name
        self.other_list = other_list

list1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
list2 = [4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]

def add_five(x): return x+5
list1 = map(add_five, list1)
#or instead you can use a lambda
list1 = map(lambda x: x+5 , list1)
```

EDIT: maybe try this.

```
for class_name in class_names:
    class_name.list_name = map(lambda x: x+5 , class_name.list_name)
```

Comment: you could use a lambda instead of `add_five`

Comment: @Pynchia Added to my example. Haven't used lambda much, so it doesn't always come to mind first.

Comment: this edits the list before putting it into the class. In the real code I'm using, not this paired down code, I have to edit the list after it's been put into the class. I want the class list_name to be edited.

Comment: @Wilsonwatson Your explanation is pretty confusing. Your terminology is a bit off. list_name isn't a class it is a list member of the class. I made an edit which should modify this member inside each of the objects inthe list of objects (instances of the class you defined).

Comment: sorry I'm not very familiar with all of this, that's why I'm having so much trouble. I tried using your edit and got this: TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Comment: I thought it would support iteration because it's a list...?

Comment: It just worked for me the python console. Ar you sure it is type 'list'? try printing "type(class_name.list_name)" to be sure

Comment: Lists do support iteration. Also who cares if the code we're showing you references a list that is a member of a class or not? A list is a list, regardless of what its name is and where it's stored in memory. If you can't take code for a generic list and figure out how to adapt it to reference a list inside a class, you are gonna have major trouble getting help on StackOverflow. Have you gone through Dive Into Python or the CodeAcademy classes yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment one of two lists stored as a list of pairs, this should work:

```
[x.list_name+5.0 for x in class_names]
```

x isn't a number, it's the class_name object. You want to retrieve the thing you want to increment from x (x.list_name) and then add 5.0.

Comment: that prints what I want, but I'd like to actually modify list_name so that when I reprint list_name from the class it gives me the modified +5.0 value

Comment: Then change it to a regular for loop instead of a list comprehension. This code creates a new list. You presumably want `for i, element in enumerate(x.list_name): x.list_name[i] += 5.0` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the value to the instance first then accessing the attribute.

```
class class_name:
    def __init__(self,list_name,other_list):
        self.list_name = list_name
        self.other_list = other_list

list1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
list2 = [4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]    

class_names = [0]*len(list1)    

for i,(l1,l2) in enumerate(zip(list1,list2)):
    class_names[i] = class_name(l1,l2)

print [x.list_name+5.0 for x in class_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but I have created a simple example:

```
class class_name(object):
    def __init__(self,list_name,other_list):
        self.list_name = list_name
        self.other_list = other_list

        self.list1 = []
        self.list2 = []

        self.list1.append(self.list_name)
        self.list2.append(self.other_list)

        print "My List1: ", self.list1
        print "My List2: ", self.list2

def input_data():
    list_one = raw_input("Data for list 1: ")
    list_two = raw_input("Data for list 2: ")

    class_name(list_one, list_two)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_data()
```

Is that what you want to?